# Access Rights to dll in System32

Tags: c#, dll, system32

I am using [EZtwain](http://www.eztwain.com/) to scan documents into a directory.

The EZTwain application installs a dll into the users system32 folder beforehand.

Now the application is working on my own personal computer, but when This application is run on the users computes who have rights restrictions, the application does not scan the images.

I take it the rights the user have restricts them from accessing the dll as it should. Is there another way to right this without giving the user full admin access on his or her pc to get to the dll in System32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place the DLL to user accessible path and register it.

Comment: You can't. EZTwain installs it for you. And the code / classes references it where it installed it to.

Comment: Found out you were right
You just need the access key and username you got from eztwain and insert that into your code. Then you can just copy the dlls into your bin directory and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Read below link and if it is ok then create batch file and use it

http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/53.htm

Comment: Thats cool, ill give you that. didnt know you can do that.
Will let you know if it worked